# Is there an efficient $O(n^2)$ way to estimate in MATLAB a matrix condition number given its LDL decomposition?

Tags: matrices, matlab, matrix-decomposition

Since evaluating a matrix condition number usually takes $O(n^3)$, I wonder whether there is an efficient $O(n^2)$ way to estimate in MATLAB a matrix condition number given its LDL decomposition.

Thank you!

Comment: $\ell_2$ condition number?

Comment: Assume that you matrix is positive definite: You could the decomposition to run some steps of the inverse iteration without shift to get the smallest eigenvalue.

Comment: @user251257: Yes, norm2 condition number. I didn't understand your answer.

Comment: In case the matrix is positive definite, the condition number is the largest eigenvalue / smallest eigenvalue. You can obtain both using power iteration. Since the convergence is quadratic, you don't need many steps.

Comment: Sorry, but can you be more specific in how to do it given LDL decomposition?

Comment: In the inverse iteration, you need to solve a linear equation with the matrix. Since you have a decomposition of that matrix, you could use it to that linear equation.

Comment: @user251257 You do not need to assume that the matrix is positive definite. The inverse iteration will give an estimate of the eigenvalue smallest in magnitude which is exactly what is needed for the spectral condition number.

Comment: @AlgebraicPavel I just don't want to deal with the case, if the matrix is singular :P